# What makes PdfStamper to remove images from pdf after cleanup() though it shouldn't?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Fist of all, I'm relatively new to java, as well to iText.

Shortly, I have a program which copies every 2 pages from big source pdf document and creates a new doc for each pair of pages. Additionally, the program removes some text information from the first page and protects new documents with owner password.

Here is my code. I use iText 5.5.13.

```
    //...
    final Rectangle RECT_TOP= new Rectangle(25f, 788f, 288f, 812.5f);  
    final Rectangle RECT_BOT= new Rectangle(103.5f, 36.5f, 331f, 40f); 
    //...

    PdfDocument document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf");
    PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(
            document, //PdfDocument
            new FileOutputStream(tempFile.getAbsolutePath()));  

   document.open(); 

    writer.addPage( writer.getImportedPage(reader, i) );
    writer.addPage( writer.getImportedPage(reader, i + 1) );                                        

    writer.freeReader(reader);
    writer.close();
    document.close(); 

    PdfReader tmpReader = new PdfReader(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    PdfStamper st = new PdfStamper(tmpReader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> locations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
    locations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, RECT_TOP, BaseColor.WHITE));
    locations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, RECT_BOT, BaseColor.WHITE));

    new PdfCleanUpProcessor(locations, st).cleanUp();                                                                   
    st.setEncryption(   
        "".getBytes(),
        OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),  
        PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);  

    st.getWriter().freeReader(tmpReader);
    st.close();
    tmpReader.close();
    tempFile.delete();
```

Source PDFs have a QR code as image on every page that I have to cleanUp(). Regions RECT_TOP and RECT_BOT don't include the image in any way.

I tested my code on two pdf with the same data inside. One of them was created with BullZip PDF printer (v PDF-1.5) and the other one with Foxit PDF printer (v PDF-1.7). The thing is the cleanUp method removes the **QR code** and data from rectangle  locations passed to PdfCleanUpProcessor in BullZip-created docs, but for foxit PDFs it works as it should and I really need it working with Bullzip docs.

I tried to manipulate the version of the temp pdf file and cleanUp() through redacted annotations, but with no use.

I want to understand where to look at and what to change (maybe somewhere in PdfCleanUpProcessor class?) to make it work properly. 
**Does anybody know why this happens?**

*UPD. I managed to create some PDFs similar to ones I need to process and I found out another interesting thing: Bullzip is able to create both "bad" and "good" files itself. I checked different printer settings, including permissions, but it is still hard to say what it depends on. Among the noticable differences there is only a slightly smaller file size and a little different page margins.*

*Anyway, here my [test files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1buvmQCiHhrbVD_i0mJhrdCo3YM9ngL3p?usp=sharing)*

Comment: This is an issue specific to the PDF in question; as you determined yourself for two identical looking PDFs it happens only in one case. If you hope for help, therefore, you really should provide an example. *"I tested the code on two pdf with the same data inside. ... for BullZip-created docs the cleanUp method removes the image and data from locations on page I passed to PdfCleanUpProcessor, for foxit PDFs it works as it should"* -  this sounds like you have an idea how to produce an example PDF, create something similar to your PDF using BullZip.

Comment: @mkl, right, I didn't think about that somehow. Anyway the question is updated with new info.

Comment: In case of the bad PDF the QR code is an inline image (i.e. the image data are immediately embedded in the page content stream), in case of the good PDF it is an image resource referenced from the content stream. Apparently iText has problems properly parsing the image which causes it to be removed during redaction. BTW, not only iText has problems, Adobe Reader has, too, but partially recovers: Adobe Reader displays the image somehow but does not allow to select it while it does allow to in the good PDF which is a sign that it has had problems with it. I'll try and inspect in detail later.

Comment: @mkl, Well, this is something. I checked the iText code processing the pages and as far as I can see the wrong things occur in processContent method of the PdfContentStreamProcessor. There is piece of code for inline images, but I'm not sure what exactly happens there and whether the code for inline images can be corrected for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed found a bug in the iText 5 `PdfCleanUpProcessor`: **It drops all *inline* images which are not partially subject to redaction.**

#### The bug in detail

The bug is located in the `PdfCleanUpRenderListener` method `renderImage`:

```
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    List<Rectangle> areasToBeCleaned = getImageAreasToBeCleaned(renderInfo);

    if (areasToBeCleaned == null) {
        chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(false, null));
    } else if ( areasToBeCleaned.size() > 0) {
        try {
            PdfImageObject pdfImage = renderInfo.getImage();
            byte[] imageBytes = processImage(pdfImage.getImageAsBytes(), areasToBeCleaned);

            if (renderInfo.getRef() == null && pdfImage != null) { // true => inline image
                PdfDictionary dict = pdfImage.getDictionary();
                PdfObject imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IMAGEMASK);
                Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);

                if (imageMask == null) {
                    imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IM);
                }

                if (imageMask != null && imageMask.equals(PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE)) {
                    image.makeMask();
                }

                PdfContentByte canvas = getContext().getCanvas();
                canvas.addImage(image, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, true);
            } else if (pdfImage != null && imageBytes != pdfImage.getImageAsBytes()) {
                chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(true, imageBytes));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedPdfException pdfException) {
            chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(false, null));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Inline images require special treatment here: For non-inlined images the actual instruction for drawing the image XObject is handled elsewhere and `renderImage` only needs to check whether the image has to be redacted and provide a redacted image version. For inline images, though, this method also has to add the image to the result content stream (unless it is completely redacted away).

As you can see there is a special treatment of inline images in the block for images partially covered by redaction areas (`areasToBeCleaned.size() > 0`) but none for images not covered by redaction areas (`areasToBeCleaned != null` and `areasToBeCleaned.size() == 0`).

#### How to fix it

You can fix this by adding a similar special treatment in a new `else` clause:

```
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    List<Rectangle> areasToBeCleaned = getImageAreasToBeCleaned(renderInfo);

    if (areasToBeCleaned == null) {
        chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(false, null));
    } else if ( areasToBeCleaned.size() > 0) {
        try {
            PdfImageObject pdfImage = renderInfo.getImage();
            byte[] imageBytes = processImage(pdfImage.getImageAsBytes(), areasToBeCleaned);

            if (renderInfo.getRef() == null && pdfImage != null) { // true => inline image
                PdfDictionary dict = pdfImage.getDictionary();
                PdfObject imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IMAGEMASK);
                Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);

                if (imageMask == null) {
                    imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IM);
                }

                if (imageMask != null && imageMask.equals(PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE)) {
                    image.makeMask();
                }

                PdfContentByte canvas = getContext().getCanvas();
                canvas.addImage(image, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, true);
            } else if (pdfImage != null && imageBytes != pdfImage.getImageAsBytes()) {
                chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(true, imageBytes));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedPdfException pdfException) {
            chunks.add(new PdfCleanUpContentChunk.Image(false, null));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else { // add inline images not subject to redaction to the content
        try {
            PdfImageObject pdfImage = renderInfo.getImage();
            if (renderInfo.getRef() == null && pdfImage != null) { // true => inline image
                PdfDictionary dict = pdfImage.getDictionary();
                PdfObject imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IMAGEMASK);
                Image image = Image.getInstance(pdfImage.getImageAsBytes());

                if (imageMask == null) {
                    imageMask = dict.get(PdfName.IM);
                }

                if (imageMask != null && imageMask.equals(PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE)) {
                    image.makeMask();
                }

                PdfContentByte canvas = getContext().getCanvas();
                canvas.addImage(image, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example

To illustrate the issue and the effect of the fix, I created a simple PDF with five inline images:

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(500, 500));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    canvas.addImage(image, 50, 0, 0, 50, i * 100 + 25, i * 100 + 25, true);
}
document.close();
```

*([RedactWithImageIssue](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactWithImageIssue.java#L194) helper method `createPdfWithInlineImages`)*

looking like this:

[image: screenshot]

Applying redaction like this

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
List<com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation> locations = new ArrayList<>();
locations.add(new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(150, 150, 350, 350), BaseColor.RED));
new PdfCleanUpProcessor(locations, stamper).cleanUp();
stamper.close();
```

*([RedactWithImageIssue](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactWithImageIssue.java#L177) test `testRedactPdfWithInlineImages`)*

without and with the patch respectively results in

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, originally only the partially redacted inline images remained but with the patch inline images completely outside the redaction area remain, too.